# Dart check if array of maps contains a specific map

Tags: dart

I want to check if an array of maps contains a specific `map`.

```
void main() {
  List<Map> mapArray = [{"a":1,"b":1}];
  print(mapArray.contains({"a":1,"b":1})); // prints false
}
```

Even though the `mapArray` array contains that `{"a":1,"b":1}` map, `mapArray.contains` function will return false.
I've found a solution by converting the maps into strings and checking if the array contains that string.

```
print(mapArray.map((x)=>x.toString()).contains({"a":1,"b":1}.toString())); // prints true
```

However, this doesn't look like the best solution. Please let me know if there is a better workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `equals` method of `DeepCollectionEquality`:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  List<Map> mapArray = [{"a":1,"b":1}, {"c":25,"d":99}];
  print(mapArray.any((element) => DeepCollectionEquality().equals(element, {"a":1,"b":1})));
}
```